# update database data from Excel , Debug : a value of DataRow from excel table is empty intsead a real value

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, excel

I developed a web appication that import database data from Excel using ASP.NET and C#.
This is a code sequence that dose not work properly **sometime**.For example when i import a excel file to database and one of row verify condition(that is working) string equal between **Agentie**(from data base) and **_Agentie**(from excel file) it should update all data row in database but is do work just if the data is numeric(from excel) else it will update like empty.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
[AgentieID]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[NrCrt]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Agentie]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Intrare]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Iesire]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Explicatii] VARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
[Operator]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Data_Ora]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Sold]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[UltimaOp]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Zile]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AgentieID] ASC)
```

);

```
        protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImportDocument"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);

                string conString = "";
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                if (ext.ToLower() == ".xls")
                {
                    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; ;
                }
                else if (ext.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }


                string query = "Select [NrCrt],[Agentie],[Intrare],[Iesire],[Explicatii],[Operator],[Data_Ora],[Sold],[UltimaOp],[Zile] from [Agentii$]";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }                   
               OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);                   
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                da.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

                // Import to Database
                using (databaseAgentii3Entities dc = new databaseAgentii3Entities())
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                    ////////////////////////////Here is a problem !!!////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        string _Agentie = dr["Agentie"].ToString();
                        string _Sold = dr["Sold"].ToString();
                         var v = dc.Tables.Where(a => string.Equals(a.Agentie, _Agentie)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (v != null)
                        {
                            // Update here
                            //v.AgentieID = dr["AgentieID"].ToString();
                            v.NrCrt = dr["NrCrt"].ToString();
                            v.Agentie = dr["Agentie"].ToString();
                            v.Intrare = dr["Intrare"].ToString();
                            v.Iesire = dr["Iesire"].ToString();
                            v.Explicatii = dr["Explicatii"].ToString();
                            v.Operator = dr["Operator"].ToString();
                            v.Data_Ora = dr["Data_Ora"].ToString();
                            v.Sold = dr["Sold"].ToString();
                            v.UltimaOp = dr["UltimaOp"].ToString();
                            v.Zile = dr["Zile"].ToString();
                        }
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        else
                        {
                            // Insert
                            dc.Tables.Add(new Table
                            {
                                //AgentieID = dr["AgentieID"].ToString(),
                                NrCrt = dr["NrCrt"].ToString(),
                                Agentie = dr["Agentie"].ToString(),
                                Intrare = dr["Intrare"].ToString(),
                                Iesire = dr["Iesire"].ToString(),
                                Explicatii = dr["Explicatii"].ToString(),
                                Operator = dr["Operator"].ToString(),
                                Data_Ora = dr["Data_Ora"].ToString(),
                                Sold = dr["Sold"].ToString(),
                                UltimaOp = dr["UltimaOp"].ToString(),
                                Zile = dr["Zile"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    dc.SaveChanges();
                }

                populateDatabaseData();
                lblMessage.Text = "Successfully data import done!";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using visual studio, why not put a break point and see what are the data types which are not matching or causing the issue..you will see the problem and will be able to fix it.

Comment: I did it and i discovered when is a problem :  a value of row that should be update it will update by replacing value with the empty one just if before was a Int value (ex "2323") and i want to update to a string (ex "asdas").

Comment: In debug i seen DataRow dr and dr[3] value is " {} " instead of vaue "asdas" as in excel.

Comment: if you can show few lines of excel (may be change the content if sensitive) one may be able to test your code and respond back

Comment: https://ibb.co/gWBieG   I uploaded a image to explain the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you have columns in Excel with a mix of string and numeric data change your connection string to use `IMEX=1` instead of `IMEX=2` to indicate the mixed column type. Otherwise if there are enough numeric values it will be assumed that the column is numeric and any non numeric values will be blanked.